# showing that a local diffeomorphism is a local isometry using first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry

In differential geometry, there is a theorem about 1st fundamental form :

A local diffeomorphism $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ is a local isometry
$\Leftrightarrow$ For any patch $\sigma$ of $S_1$, $\sigma$ and $f \circ \sigma$ have the same 1st fundamental form.

In some examples of my text (A.Pressley), the author just found a patch satisfying the above property, and said that it is enough.

I think, however, it is not enough because the patch is not 'any' patch.......
Why did he solve the problem???

Comment: but, to prove smoothness of a map, if we have smoothness with respect to one local coordinate representative then it follows that all others are likewise smooth. This follows because they can be reached by composition of transition functions which are themselves smooth. I suspect something similar is true here, but I don't have all the definitions in front of me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to check the condition for an atlas of patches - checking for a single patch $\sigma$ shows that $f$ is a local isometry on the image of $\sigma$, so to show that $f$ is a local isometry everywhere you need to check a collection $\Sigma$ of patches that cover the surface. Once you have this then the result for arbitrary patches follows per James' comment:

For any other patch $\sigma$ you can cover the image of $\sigma$ with patches $\{\sigma_i\}\subset\Sigma$ with corresponding transition functions $\phi_i = \sigma_i^{-1} \circ \sigma$, and thus for any vectors $u,v$ based at a point in $\sigma$ there is an $i$ such that the patch $\sigma_i$ contains the base point. The action of the first fundamental form of $f \circ \sigma= f\circ \sigma_i \circ \phi_i$ on these vectors is thus

$$
\begin{align}
 g_{f\circ \sigma}(u,v) &= \langle df \circ d\sigma_i (d\phi_i (u)), df \circ d\sigma_i (d\phi_i (v)) \rangle \\
&= g_{f \circ \sigma_i}(d\phi_i(u), d\phi_i(v))\\
&= g_{\sigma_i}(d\phi_i(u), d\phi_i(v))\\
&= g_{\sigma_i \circ \phi_i}(u,v) = g_{\sigma}(u,v)
\end{align}$$

where we use the fact that $\sigma_i$ and $f \circ \sigma_i$ have the same first fundamental form to go from the second to the third line.

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you very much~~